# Inherit class functions from multiple classes

Tags: php

I am making a bot that can have addons. I need help with how to structure and how I can include the commands from the addons into the main object.

So the main bot is very bare bones, it has the $bot object with some commands. For example:

```
namespace Bot;

... the bot class ..

Usage:
$bot = new Bot();
$bot->say('hello');
```

I have this file in Commands/Bot.php

Now I make an addon Commands/Help.php

Here I make a class with help commands. Now how can I insert this into $bot so I can use it as follows:

```
$bot->help->showHelp();
```

Where the help class is a child of $bot.

I somehow need to "register" that the Help commands exist I guess in a config file. Then include it in the main Bot.php class with a loop.

But then what? How do I get it to be a child and append inside $bot?

A second approach:

Maybe it is bad to load *all commmands all the time* due to memory consumption?

So if you declare what bot commands to use:

```
use Bot\Commands\Talk;
use Bot\Commands\Help;
```

I still want to merge these two into:

```
$bot->say();
$bot->help->showHelp();
```

Thanks.

Comment: you should look up some basic programing patterns, such as factory or decorator.

Comment: Autoloader and Dependency Injection will do the trick for you. There're some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/779/dependency-injection#t=201609031956103774342

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Dependency Injection. Pass the Help object to the Bot's constructor which then gets assigned to the Bot's public $help property.  You can then call the methods of the help object using $bot->help->helpMethod();  Check out some more examples [here](http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html).

```
class Bot{

    public $help;

    public function __construct(Help $help){

        $this->help = $help;
    }

    public function say(){
        echo "Talking...";
    }
}


class Help{

    public function showHelp(){

        echo "Help is shown";
    }
}

// instantiate the help object and pass it into the bot constructor
$bot = new Bot(new Help());
$bot->say();
$bot->help->showHelp();
```